# How to reduce complexity of this method?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-7

PS: CONST*-* =>constants

I need to reduce complexity of this method with Java 7 syntax.

```
public void myMethod(){
    if(condition1){
       menu.addItem(CONSTA-1);
    }
    if(condition2){
        menu.addItem(CONSTB-1);
    }
    if(condition3){
        menu.addItem(CONSTC-1);
        menu.addItem(CONSTC-2);
    }
    if(condition4){
        menu.addItem(CONSTD-1);
    }
    if(condition5){
        menu.addItem(CONSTE-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to reduce the number of conditions if they are all totally independent from one another. I'd suggest looking to remove the [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Other than that, we can't help you with the limited amount of context you've given us.

Comment: When I read the title I was expecting I huge method, with multiple nesting levels, etc. So yeah 1. Nothing to simplify here, 2. Code optimization is part of [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: this structure of method  used in many lines, i use sonarQube,
it shown me this comment  "The Cyclomatic Complexity of this method..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basic rule for refactoring is, method should be small enough to accommodate functionality

So by this we can easily refactor like below,

```
public void myMethod(){
  addMenuCondition1(menu);
  addMenuCondition2(menu);
  addMenuCondition3(menu);
  addMenuCondition4(menu);
  addMenuCondition5(menu);
}
public void addMenuCondition1(Menu menu) {
   if(condition1){
       menu.addItem(CONSTA-1);
    }
}
public void addMenuCondition2(Menu menu) {
 if(condition2){
        menu.addItem(CONSTB-1);
    }
}
public void addMenuCondition3(Menu menu) {
 if(condition3){
        menu.addItem(CONSTC-1);
        menu.addItem(CONSTC-2);
    }
}
public void addMenuCondition4(Menu menu) {
  if(condition4){
        menu.addItem(CONSTD-1);
    }
}
public void addMenuCondition5(Menu menu) {
   if(condition5){
        menu.addItem(CONSTE-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, you could think about using a `List<Pair<Predicate, List<MenuItem>>` thingy.

In other words: when it is possible to extract each condition into a standalone *Predicate* object, then you could do something like:

```
for (Pair<Predicate, List<MenuItem> pair : thatList) {
  if (pair.first().test()) {
    pair.second().foreach(menu::addItem);
```

Meaning: you iterate all conditions, and for the first match, you retrieve the corresponding menu items and have them added. Where the crucial part is to figure a sane way to actually have each `test()` to 
the right thing.

You could do similar things in Java7 (by implementing the required classes yourself). But that would be rather *over-engineering* things in my eyes.